# Running script from BBEdit/TextWrangler gives "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified"

Tags: terminal, mac, python, bbedit

If I write a script in BBEdit/TextWrangler, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 1234
```

and choose "Run" from the `#!` menu, I get this in a new document:

```
1234
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

How do I get rid of those 3 extra lines?

Comment: Change your shell init so that it's smart enough to know whether the shell that's being started is interactive or not, and not do whatever it's doing if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

[The solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch) is to enclose any use of `tput` in `.bash_profile` within a test for interactive shell, i.e.:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
  #tput command
  #tput command
  #tput command
  #etc
fi
```

Comment: That's shell syntax, not Python.